# fql / / facebook the other user's comment content

Tags: facebook-fql

Can not speak English well. Understand your

Want to search for the contents of any person's comment.
How do you want to use fql query statement?

ex)

```
SELECT commentsFROM stream
WHERE filter_key IN

(SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me ())

AND actor_id IN

(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me ())
```

Not about me, I would like to see the comments of other users.
Help ~
Thank you ~